# Classifying abelian extensions of number fields with class field theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field, adeles

I am reading about local class field theory here https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes24.pdf and in the end the author mentions an application to count the number of Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with degree $p$ for an odd prime $p$. It works as below.

By local class field theory, it suffices to count the number of open subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ with index $p$. Since the extension has degree $p$, its norm subgroup must contain ${\mathbb{Q}_p^\times}^p$ so we just need to count the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/{\mathbb{Q}_p^\times}^p$ with index $p$. The projection $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times\to\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/{\mathbb{Q}_p^\times}^p$ is continuous and the latter is discrete so this makes sure that we indeed get the open subgroups.

$\mathbb{Q}_p^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$, so $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/{\mathbb{Q}_p^\times}^p\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p)^2$.  Our job is now just counting number of cyclic order $p$ subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^2$. There are $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=p+1$ of them.

I wonder if there is application like this for number fields? Maybe we can classify all abelian extensions of a number field by looking at the quotient of its idele groups. But I have no clue how. The group of ideles is a direct limit and I try to pass the direct limit to the quotient, but I am not sure how precisely I work.

Edits: **is the claim below true?** The number of finite abelian Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ and discriminant dividing $D$ is same as the number of index $n$ subgroups in $\left( \mathbb{Z} / D \mathbb{Z} \right) ^{\times}$.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by "classify". Certainly, there's no hope of counting extensions – there are infinitely many of any degree. Finite abelian extensions of a number field $K$ are in bijection with Hecke characters $\mathbb A_K^\times\to \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: I think the characterization you ask for is given in Theorem 28.7 (p. 5) here: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2021fa/LectureNotes28.pdf . The proof is given in later lectures: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.786/lectures.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give a tentative answer to your question, elaborating the comments.

Let us do the example of $\mathbb{Q}$ first. As there are infinitely many extensions of degree $n$, what you have done is kind of impossible. But if we take a discriminant $D$, then there are finitely many extension. Now, as suggested in the comments that the finite abelian Galois extensions are in one-to-one correspondence with Hecke characters (here Dirichlet characters), the number of finite abelian Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ and discriminant dividing $D$ is same as the number of index $n$ subgroups in $\left( \mathbb{Z} / D \mathbb{Z} \right) ^{\times}$.

Now, question is "why discrimininant?". In the case of local field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, there is only one prime. We are using discriminant to bound the ramification in the case of number fields as there are infinitely many primes.

To answer the same question in general is difficult. Even for local field case, the structure of $\mathcal{O}^\times$ (the unit group of the ring of integers) is difficult to understand. So understanding ramified extensions is tough.

A small remark for the result for $\mathbb{Q}$ can also be achieved using Kronecker-Weber theorem.

Comment: Why is the number of finite abelian Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ and discriminant $D$ the numbe of index $n$ subgroups in $(\mathbb{Z}/D)^\times$?

Comment: I don't think this is quite right - maybe you want discriminant dividing $D$? For example, $(\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z)^\times$ has multiple index $2$ subgroups, but there is just 1 number field with discriminant $8$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Indeed. It could be dividing $D$. For the case of finite abelian extensions with degree 2 and discriminant dividing 8, there are 3 such extensiosn by http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?hst=List&degree=2&discriminant=8%2C-8%2C4%2C-4%2C2%2C-2%2C1%2C-1&search_type=List.

Comment: @Mathmo123 For degree $n = 2$ and discriminant $D = 8$, we have $(\mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$. So there are 2 subgroups of index 2. Also there are 2 extensions, viz, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i})$. Here we are taking absolute value of discriminant.

Comment: @Ja_1941 As I mentioned in the previous comment, taking absolute value of the discriminant will solve the problem. I think, the conductor of Dirichlet characters determine the discriminant upto sign. So, I made the statement.

Comment: @Offlaw There should be 3 index 2 subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$, generated by $(0,1)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. There are however two exntensions as you mention with degree 2 and discriminant 8 or -8.

Comment: @Offlaw By the way, I am not that familiar with dirichlet characters. Do you know any references for that? Thank you.

Comment: @Ja_1941, Sorry, I made a silly mistake. $(\mathbb{Z} / M \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \subset (\mathbb{Z} / D \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ if $M \mid D$. You're right. I'll make the edit. Also, general reference for ANT is Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory".